# What was the service offered by US Sprint for long distance data connections in the late 1980's?

Tags: modem, bbs

Back in the 1980's long distance telephone calls were ridiculously expensive.  This led more than one young aspiring geek to misuse the phone network when making those *oh so important* calls to BBS's on the other end of the country.  But I remember sometime around 1988 that US Sprint offered a service where you could call a local number using your computer/modem and connect to some sort of network.  After authentication, it was possible to *route* your connection to another city, and finally dial out like you were local in that city.  This resulted in the ability to make long distance connections at a fraction of the cost, and I seem to remember the bandwidth wasn't too shabby either.  Does anyone remember the name of this service, or any details about it?  I was just curious how it worked, what infrastructure it used, how popular it was, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [Telenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telenet) (renamed to "Sprintnet" when Sprint acquired it) or [Tymnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tymnet).

Tymnet did not survive and Sprintnet became part of what we now know as the Internet.

Comment: Bingo!  The service I was thinking of was PC Pursuit, which was offered by Telenet in the late 80's.  thanks!